# Abstracting PSQL Write Query

Tags: postgresql, go, interface, abstraction

I have a typical function that takes a post request from the frontend and decodes the data into a struct in order to put it into a psql database. You can see the code below. My problem is that I want to be able to abstract this function so that I can give it any amount of variables of any type so that for every request I don't have to have a separate write handler.

It looks difficult because I would have to somehow pass in a way to abstract `var profitReq profitReq` to work for any struct. If golang had some sort of eval string method I would know how to do this, but someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think that it does.

The other place I need to change is in QueryRow - I have to be able to pass it in a variable number of variables. I could construct the string easily enough, but I'm not sure how to append variables to that QueryRow necessarily. If I append all the variables to an array for example, I can't pass that array into QueryRow as that's not how it's structured. Again, here some sort of eval statement would help.

I'm new to golang, but I've seen a lot of cool things related to interfaces, which I admittedly don't understand very well. Would there be a way to use an interface here that would help?

Thanks to anyone who can help!

```
func Write_profit_table(profitWriteChannel chan string, profitType string, req *http.Request) {
    var profitReq profitReq;
    err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&profitReq);
    if err!=nil{
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    NotInDB, _ := Search_userinfo_table(profitReq.Email)

    if NotInDB == false {
        var lastInsertId int
        err2 := db.QueryRow("INSERT INTO profit(email, type, dateArray, amount, interest, compounded, recurring, name, description, profitFrom) 
                VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) returning uid;", 
                profitReq.Email, profitReq.Type, pq.Array(profitReq.DateArray), profitReq.Profit, profitReq.Interest, 
                profitReq.Compounded, profitReq.Recurring, profitReq.Name, profitReq.Description, profitReq.ProfitFrom).Scan(&lastInsertId);
        if err2!=nil{
            log.Panic(err2)
        }
    }

    profitWriteChannel<-"finished writing to profit"
}
```

Comment: If that's what you're looking for, accept that you'll be giving up performance for convenience, and either use an ORM package like [GORM](http://gorm.io/) or use a language other than Go.  I don't recommend trying to write your own ORM -- which sounds like the direction you're currently headed in -- as it's a notorious tempting quagmire, see e.g. [ORM Hate by Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/OrmHate.html) ("the Vietnam of computer science").  If you want performance and convenience look to code generation (or even just a powerful text editor and some elbow grease) instead.

Comment: Maybe it's bloody minded purism, but I really don't want to solve my problem by adding an abstraction between me and the db. I'm wary of using dependencies unless I have to (like a graphing library or some such), because it adds another black box where errors can occur that I have to debug. I'm not convinced that the postgres drivers are not good enough yet, sorry :<.

Comment: I don't advocate GORM unless you're looking for really rapid development. My purism would prevent me from using a single write handler -- which you say you want to do -- reflection is too high a performance cost for me to accept in most applications, and added complexity as well which makes room for lots of bugs. So basically nothing but downside from my perspective. Instead I would just parse the DDL and generate query functions automatically: compile-time work rather than runtime work. But to each his own.

Comment: Well, yeah idk. I'm probably not going to use the reflect abstraction written below as I'm worried about how to reason about the code later (DRY vs. 'how the heck did I do this 6 months ago'). Shrug. Go needs generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is called generics.
Generics are not supported by Go 1.x
Luckily for us, there's a [proposal for them for Go 2 (called Contracts)](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/go2draft-contracts.md)

What can you do until then?

1. Duplicate your code (probably what you're doing now)
2. Use interfaces
   If you know that this method will always query by email, you could create simple interface for that purpose: `type Emailer interface { Email() string }`
3. Use empty interface (`interface{}`) and reflection to figure out what columns you have.
4. Write your own generator. A bit like (1), but you don't have to do this yourself.

Here's the gist of it:
https://play.golang.org/p/A_2YKWLvmn-

Comment: I'd like to do a combination of 2) and 3) but I'm not sure how. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sure. But could you add at least two different structs you plan in using? I can invent mine, of course, for the example, but I think that will be more efficient if I use something you plan to use later.

Comment: Oh hey thanks for getting back to me @alexey. Well my structs will all be single layer deep json calls with arrays of strings, ints, floats, or plain strings. Something like this https://hastebin.com/emejicasud.cpp. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I added a gist for you.